# RDS Licensing not actually licensing

Tags: remote-desktop-services, licensing

I have a few RDS hosts spread over two AD domains. The RDS servers in the top domain (`enets.local`) are fine, they get their licenses and consume them at a healthy rate.

However, the RDS hosts in the child domain (`myflo.enets.local`) do not seem to be consuming any licenses. Due to Server 2008 R2's "honesty" licensing system at the moment, this isn't actually causing any service interruptions, but it may be cause for concern when we audit our licenses.

[image]

The license server is active and available, but as you can see in the above screenshot, it's stating there are no licenses and that there are problems. But the diagnosis screen shows nothing, and the event log has nothing of any interest to report.

There is a two-way trust between the two domains (as is default for child domains).

What else can I look for to get the RDS hosts in the child domain consuming licenses from the parent domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually troubleshooting a *different* issue today and `dcdiag` threw this interesting tidbit up:

> Time Generated: 05/04/2012   11:32:43
>
> Event String:
>
> The Remote Desktop license server cannot update the license attributes for user "firstname.lastname" in the Active Directory Domain
>   "myflo.enets.local". Ensure that the computer account for the license
>   server is a member of Terminal Server License Servers group in Active
>   Directory domain "myflo.enets.local". A warning event occurred. 
>   EventID: 0xC9001009

I've added the licensing server into the group in the child domain, and it looks like everything is back to consuming licences again.

Comment: I had this two weeks ago, but the RDS evaluation period had already lapsed. Same issue, though... Needed to move the terminal server into the license group in AD.